# How to animate react-bootstrap progress bar using jquery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I need your help making this progress bar animate starts from 0 to now value I have tried jquery code for an hour but the animation didn't behave the way it should be. Need your help guys. Thank you in advance.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';

function ProgressBar() {
var delay = 1500;
$(".progress-bar").each(function(){
    $(this).animate( { width: $(this).attr('aria-valuenow') + '%' }, delay );
});
return (
<ProgressBar className="ProgressBar" now={95} />
<ProgressBar className="ProgressBar" now={55} />
<ProgressBar className="ProgressBar" now={50} />
);
}

export default ProgressBar;
```

**Here's the output:**
[image: Out]

Comment: You might consider using the HTML5 `<progress>` element.  It will behave very predictably, and all you have to do is update the `value` attribute.  I’m not sure, but I believe you can also tweak its appearance with CSS.  Documentation for `<progress>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `animated` props. I think that would suffice. Attaching a codesandbox for clarity.

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-diffie-ghizg?file=/src/App.js